# Previous record in mysql with duplicated records and random ID

Tags: mysql

My applicants table has multiple records with the same date and an index with missing and non-sequential values, much like this:

```
ID      date          Name
3422    2021-02-08    Priscilla
3421    2021-02-04    Rahul
3437    2021-02-04    Ella
3435    2021-02-04    Aarushi
3436    2020-02-03    Colin
```

I need to get the previous record to the current one in database order by date. So if the current record is Ella's I need to return Rahul's and then Priscilla's.

I've dealt with the `next` equivalent by using an IN statement to exclude IDs in multiple dates:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM applicants
 WHERE date_created <= $mdata['currdate']
   AND applicant_id NOT IN ( . $mdata['currids'] . )
 ORDER 
    BY date_created DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

But this doesn't work with `previous` calls.

I've seen several previous answers but none quite fit my situation and I'm not versed enough in SQL to modify them to my needs. Some pointers towards to a solution will be very welcome.

Comment: Use `LAG()` function simply. But you **must** have an expression which provides shown data ordering during the sorting. If such expression not exists then the task is unsolvable - there is no positional rows ordering in a table, visible ordering is fake.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "the previous record to the current one in database order by date"? How would the result look like for the given set of input data?

Comment: There's nothing here that establishes that Priscilla's data is 'previous' to Rahul's

Comment: I now realise I have a unique column of UUIDs, which could force a consistent and repeatable order on rows. This would presumably resolve the issues. Or I could replace the index (which isn't linked to anything) and ensure future additions are sorted by date before insertion.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: mySQL version is 5.7.24,